# Array to string

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010, facebook

I have this code:

```
dynamic friends = fb.Get("/me/friends");
var friend = friends.name;
```

How to get the information from the dynamic friends object? I'm using the facebook sdk 5.2.

Comment: It has been years since I was to [Arroyo](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Arroyo) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
var fb = new FacebookWebClient();
dynamic myFriends = fb.Get("me/friends");
foreach (var friend in myFriends.data)
{
    // u can get friend.name here
}
```

Comment: for insert the list in richtextbox?

Comment: thank you very much. i have insert the code "foreach (string fn in myFriendNames) 
{ rtb.AppendText (fn + Environment.NewLine); } "
for get in richtexbox and work

Comment: sorry man but extract the subdata ex: 
data:{
"id"
"id2"
}
data3:{
"name"
}
your code extract all data

Answer (score 1):

try

```
List<string> myFriendNames = (from f in friends.data select f.name).ToList();
```

EDIT - as per comment:

```
foreach (string fn in myFriendNames)
{ rtb.AppendText (fn + Environment.NewLine); }
```

Comment: for insert the list in richtextbox?